# Stub Pusher (Event) Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, angular-test

I use [`pusher`](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#bind-events) for my sockets/events.

My pusher channels are wrapped in an object which is passed through a key/value pipe to the child component. So the actual channel is in `this.channel.value` while `this.channel.key` is just a string with the key.

### Code

```
@Input() channel;
...
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('channel.value', this.channel.value, typeof this.channel.value);
  this.channel.value.bind('client-msg', (msg) => {
  ...
  });
```

The `console.log` gives me an object `e`, I assume this is an event, of the type Object?

```
channel.value e {callbacks: t, global_callbacks: Array(0), failThrough: ƒ, name: "private-5c49fdc35abdba3fccb362795c49fe6d5cc2ea3ffcb4f895", pusher: t, …}callbacks: t {_callbacks: {…}}failThrough: ƒ (t,n)global_callbacks: []name: "private-5c49fdc35abdba3fccb362795c49fe6d5cc2ea3ffcb4f895"pusher: t {key: "0d4bf48a9d086414a4da", config: {…}, channels: t, global_emitter: t, sessionID: 123906324, …}receiver: "5c49fdc35abdba3fccb36279"receiverName: "Don Peyote"subscribed: truesubscriptionCancelled: falsesubscriptionPending: falsetype: "chat"__proto__: e object
```

### Angular/Jasmine Unit Test:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChatMessengerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.channel = {
      key: 'private-5c49fdc35abdba3fcl1fecb362795c49fe6d5cc2ea3ffcb4f895',
      value:
        {
          receiver: '5c49fdc35abdba3fccb36279',
          name: 'DonPeyote'
        }
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

### Question:

How do I create the stub/mock that I can pass my properties (receiver,name) and bind an event listener to it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the [pusher-js-mock](https://github.com/nikolalsvk/pusher-js-mock) module.

```
import { PusherMock } from "pusher-js-mock";

...

describe('ChatMessengerComponent', () => {
  let component: ChatMessengerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChatMessengerComponent>;
  const pusher = new PusherMock();

...

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChatMessengerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    const channel = pusher.subscribe('private-5c49fdc35abdba3fcl1fecb362795c49fe6d5cc2ea3ffcb4f895');
    component.channel = {
      key: 'private-5c49fdc35abdba3fcl1fecb362795c49fe6d5cc2ea3ffcb4f895',
      value: channel
    };
```